# The isolated critical point!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-topology, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis

I am confuse on the deffinition for a critical point which is called isolated. Please tell me what the isolated critical point?

Comment: Hope It help you : an example $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^4-x^2}=\sqrt{x^2(x^2-1)}\to D_f=\left\{0\right\}\cup[1,+\infty)\cup(-\infty,-1]$$ and $x=0 $ is an isolated critical point here

Comment: The tags might all be inappropriate.  In what context is the question? Critical point of what, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of critical points of a function $f : A \to B$ is 
$$
CP(f) = 
\{ 
x \in A \mid {\bf d}f_x  \text{ is not surjective}
\},
$$
where ${\bf d} f_x$ denotes the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$.
A point $x$ is an isolated critical point of $f$ if there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $
CP(f) \cap \{ y\in A \text{ s.t. } |x-y| < \delta \} = \{x\}.
$

Comment: could you tell me how i can find the defition in some book?

Comment: I think I was misled by the tags for this question and provided too general of a response.  Why are you interested in this subject?  Maybe then I can recommend an appropriate book.

Comment: I am interested in the topological degree method. It follows from the mountain pass point of Hofer type, I encountered a type of critical point which is isolated. But I don't know what the defition is, so I am here! I am a beginer in the area!

If you can show me a book which provides adequately what I need to know about this area. I sincerely thank you!

Comment: In that case I recommend "Calculus," by James Stewart.  If you want a more advanced book, you can take a look at "Elementary Classical Analysis" by Marsden.